# Flutter Navigation using a switchcase

Tags: flutter, routes, conditional-statements, widget

I am building a listview of 20 list in them and once this list view is build i want to have different pages for each of the list tile and i also want a way to navigate to each of these page seperately.

i am thinking of using the switch case and use the index oof the list for the condition which will decide based on the clicked index to navigate.

```
final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _av_all_listtiles = [
    {
     
      "id": 1,
      "name": "label 1",
    },
    {
      
      "id": 2,
      "name": "label 2",
    },
    {
    
      "id": 3,
      "name": "label 3",
    },
```

```
ListView.builder(
                            
                            
                              itemCount: _av_searched_listiles.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) => 
                                child: Card(
                                  borderOnForeground: true,
                                  elevation: 8,
       
                                  child: Container(
                                    height: 44.h,
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      
                                       onTap: () {
                                           Navigator.push(
                                           context,
                                           MaterialPageRoute(
                                           builder: (context) =>
                                           // here i want some kind of function or conditioon based on which it will navigate

                                           deposit_screen()),
                                         );
                                       },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```

I tried to make function but it didnt work

Comment: Why do you need Multiple Screens for Navigation? Is it a scenario requirement or are you missing something?

Comment: actually i have 30 listtiles which in have build using the listview.builder now i want seperate screens for each of the list tile so i was thinking to make use of the default index  as a condition for routing to diifferent screen of listtiles

Comment: Is the UI same on all screens or different?

Comment: different actually all the screens have textfileds which are again different

Comment: Can you share UI snippets , so that you can get optimised approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch case for navigation like this :

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _av_all_listtiles.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
        borderOnForeground: true,
        elevation: 8,
        child: Container(
          height: 44.h,
          child: ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              var screen = deposit_screen();
              switch (index) {
                case 0:
                  screen= deposit_screen();
                  break;
                case 1:
                  screen= deposit_screen1();
                  break;
                case 2:
                  screen= deposit_screen2();
                  break;
              }
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => screen
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i was loohing for thank khunt arpit

Comment: Is this the best way to make routing to different screen in case of 30+ listtiles or there is something more efficient and optimised method.

Comment: From my perspective, this is the best way bro...

Answer (score 0):

This is not too difficult to implement. There are few things to consider to fix your code.

1. Usage of arrow function

   When you use arrow function it means you are calling and returning the value in a single line of code. If you need to write some logic inside function first change arrow function to normal function body.

You need to change this

```
    Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) =>
       deposit_screen()),
    );
```

to

```
    Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) {
       })
    );
```

2. Now you can put your code inside this function. But for this builder to execute and navigate to a specific page, you need to return the page from here.
   For example, using the default counter code, I am trying to move to Page1 if value is even & Page2 if value is odd.
   You need to put your code like this.

```
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return (_counter %2==0 ? Page1() : Page2());
        }),
      );
```

Now the router will get the page name correctly as you are returning it from builder.

Comment: You are welcome. Also if this solved your issue then please mark the answer as accepted. So this issue could be marked as [SOLVED].